# How to solve too many TCP connections on FIN_WAIT_2?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

Server and client are connected using port 8000. Clients are aborted unexpectively but the connections are still there. Besides restarting server, any suggestion to release the legacy connections?

```
$ net stat -an | grep 8000
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.8000         127.0.0.1.58761           CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.58761        127.0.0.1.8000            FIN_WAIT_2 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.8000         127.0.0.1.58755        CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.58755        127.0.0.1.8000         FIN_WAIT_2 
tcp46      0      0  *.8000                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: add the -p flag to the netstat command. This will give you the process id's associated with each connection.

Comment: No, `-p` is not suitable for Mac OS. On client side, I can kill the process on `FIN_WAIT_2`. But after the process on client side killed, then on server side, will the `CLOSE_WAIT` connection be released. This is a question.

Comment: I think I should find a non-local environment for test.